# Where are the files generated with Xcode 4.5 in Lion?

Tags: xcode

I tried to run my program in a MacBook air with OS Lion and I cannot find the files generated, where is the new location to storage the text files? Above they were storage in the file build->Debug but in Lion I have not idea. Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Lion. Xcode puts generated files in:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

where `~` is your home directory.

Keep in mind that the `~/Library` directory is hidden by default in Lion (and later).

Comment: Thank you so much, I should write Xcode instead of Lion, my mistake. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks @rmaddy

Comment: You can increase your reputation by accepting this answer if it solves your problem. Enjoy.